# Android: Passing data from content provider to activity with global search

Tags: android, search, android-contentprovider

So I'm playing with Android TV, and I have a content provider that shows results in the global search, but I'm trying to figure out how to pass some general information in with the intent that opens a specific view in my activity. I have my searchable defined as:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:hint="Search for videos"
android:searchSettingsDescription="Description"
android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.sample.mediaplayer"
android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
android:searchSuggestIntentData="content://com.sample.mediaplayer/video_database_leanback"
android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?"
android:searchSuggestThreshold="1"
android:includeInGlobalSearch="true"
>
```

My query for the database is performs like this:

```
    String selection = KEY_NAME + " MATCH ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{query + "*"};

    return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);
```

and when I get the activity started up from a search result, I am able to pull intent data from it:

```
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        Uri intentData = intent.getData();

        for( String string : intentData.getPathSegments() ) {
            Log.e( "App", "Path Segments: " + string );
        }
```

which outputs this:

```
E/App: Path Segments: video_database_leanback
E/App: Path Segments: 2
```

I'm just trying to figure out if there's a way to access some data by column name so I can show the proper UI

Thanks!